# how to initiate a class with an interface inside an interface

Tags: c#, .net, interface

If I have an interface `MyInterface1`

```
interface MyInterface1
{
    ImyGod myproperty { get; set; }
}
```

If I have a class do the following, it complains

```
class myClass : IMyInterface1
{
    myGod myproperty { get; set; }
}
```

What should I iniatiate myClass with myGod here? 
Thanks.

Comment: Just read the compiler error message.

Comment: Please try to format your code samples readably.

Comment: I vote to close this question. Feels a lot like a troll-question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just not possible.  In order to implement an interface the signature of the member must be *exactly* the same as the signature defined in the interface.  You will either need to change the interface or the class's implementation so that the type of the property matches, exactly.

Since your property has a setter it means that, according to the interface, you would be able to set *any* object that implements `ImyGod` to that property, but since the derived class is typed to `myGod` instead, it can't support any other implementation of `ImyGod`.

What you could do is use a generic interface, like so:

```
interface MyInterface1<T> where T : ImyGod
{
    T myproperty { get; set; }
}

class myClass : IMyInterface1<myGod>
{
    myGod myproperty { get; set; }
}
```

That will compile and work as intended, and also prevent someone setting a `someOtherGod` instance to that property which it clearly can't support.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the property as public:

```
class myClass : IMyInterface1 
{ 
    public ImyGod myproperty {get; set;} 
}
```

Comment: No, I need to use myGod instead of ImyGod in myClass

Comment: @NewDTinStackoverflow if you knew the answer, why ask?

Comment: @NewDTinStackoverflow: then change your interface to `myGod`, not `ImyGod`. it's simple as that.

Comment: @NewDTinStackoverflow You should really work on formatting your code better, and using more standard naming conventions, as it will make issues like that somewhat more apparent.

Comment: @NewDTinStackoverflow: you must use ImyGod to meet interface requirement. If you want to have property of type myGod just add second property and implement appropriate logic in getter and setter.